# Why does the Republican party have such a high appeal with Christians?

Tags: united-states, parties, christianity

Why do Christians feel so inclined to subscribe to the conservative party?

Has a major Christian authority taught his subjects that it is righteous to be a Republican?

Comment: See https://oxfordre.com/religion/view/10.1093/acrefore/9780199340378.001.0001/acrefore-9780199340378-e-97 for some background.

Comment: I believe that religious branches that have a more moral fundamentalist, and general authoritarian flavor to them are going to have followers/worshipers that identify with a similar theme in a political party. I think it's more about how specific denominations align more than just Christianity itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's important to check if the Republican party actually has a high appeal with Christians. And if so, with which denominations.

The [Pew Research Center](https://www.pewforum.org/religious-landscape-study/party-affiliation/) has data on this, showing that Catholics actually lean slightly towards Democrats, mainline Protestants lean slightly towards Republicans, but this tendency only becomes prominent with more radical Christian groups.

For 47% of Democrats, Religion is "very important" (vs 69% of Republicans), so the Democratic party seems to have a high appeal to some Christians as well. But we can also see that only 25% of Democrats look to religion for guidance on what is right and wrong (vs 44% of Republicans).

An important factor to consider here is the [Christian right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_right) and the [Moral Majority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_Majority), which:

> played a key role in the mobilization of conservative Christians as a political force

The [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/28/us/religion-politics-evangelicals.html) notes:

> American evangelicals had long steered clear of politics, but with the advent of Moral Majority that was no longer so. “For really the first time in any significant way, evangelicalism becomes interlocked with the Republican Party,” Randall Balmer, a professor of religion at Dartmouth College, told Retro Report.

Important issues were related to selective Christian morality regarding sexuality and women's rights (eg opposition to homosexuality or abortion, but less so to divorce or sexual assault).

Comment: Divorce seems like a strange example as Republicans tend to frown on divorce much more than democrats. Claiming Republicans support sexual assault is also rather contentious. Perhaps stances on welfare are a better example.

Comment: Black people are overwhelmingly Christian and overwhelmingly Democratic at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelMormon Black people have other reasons for wanting to vote Democratic, and have since the 1920s, most of which center around economic issues.

Comment: I don't actually think this is a complete answer as it could be, especially considering that the long-standing joke about the Moral Majority is that it was neither moral nor a majority. A better answer would note that a large part of the issue was that the Democrats became a pro-choice party during the 70s.

Comment: @eyeballfrog very few Republican politicians who campaign for "ban divorce" vs many who campaign for "ban abortion". And they don't seem to mind putting up candidates that have divorced multiple times, or have multiple accusations of sexual assault against them.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are two main reasons for this, values, and support.

The Republican party, and widely accepted interpretations of Christian doctrine seem to line up, the fact that both things tend to hold tradition in high esteem and long to conserve what is, or what was. Those who tend to value the past tend to side with the Republican party, in this way the Republican party is made up of people that might be older for the same reasons it's made up of people who are more religious.

The Republican party supports the preservation of religious liberties, and in turn, the Christians support the Republican in an act of self-preservation. As humans, we tend to support people that speak on our behalf. You can see this on the flip side with the Democratic party and the LGBT+ community, the Democratic party is outspoken for them and in turn, they support the Democratic party.

Comment: There are many parts of the Democratic party that aligns with the Bible (ie. how to handle immigrants), why do you think its the Republican party that gets Christian support.

Comment: That's why I put "widely accepted interpretation". The church isn't made to be changed, because with change comes instability (they wouldn't have lasted this long if they changed what they thought every other week) and the Republican tend not to change because they see something good about what is or what was. it's a mindset mainly those that share the same values tend to support each other. To your point, I'm sure you could pick out a Democrat Christian and a Republican Christian because they might be reading the same book but they're drawing different conclusions.

Comment: "preservation of religious liberties" seems like a political slogan. I assume "religious" means "Christian" here, but what exactly are those "liberties"? As Christians are free to practice their religion in the US, I assume it's actually about forcing others to abide by their Christian values? Having the need for "self-preservation" in the very Christian US doesn't seem like a reasonable stance.

Comment: It might also help to look at [which specific Christian groups support Republicans](https://www.pewforum.org/religious-landscape-study/party-affiliation/). Catholics lean Democrat, mainline Protestants are split, and the more radical Christian groups such as Evangelicals favor Republicans.

Comment: @tim the Earth is infested with humans, there are billions of us, and we still self-preserve, everything self-preserves in a hierarchy whether it's at the top or bottom of that hierarchy, in fact, things that don't self-preserve go extinct.

Answer (score -2):

TL;DR: It's not so much that Christians support Republicans; it's that Christians find that many people aligned with the Democratic Party are actively destroying what Christians cherish, and the Republicans are the only alternative.

The left tends to think of "rights" in terms of "What should my government *be doing for* us?", while the right tends to think in terms of "What should my government *not be doing to* us?".

When it comes to religion, Christians feel that the Democrats are telling them that not only must they *accept* non-traditional sexual relationships, they must *embrace* the situation and *not* be critical of elements of society that promote behaviour that Christians consider inappropriate for themselves.  Christians feel they are being forced to do things they believe wrong, and that they are prevented from doing things they think are right.

According to ["'The Church Is Under Attack': CA Committee Passes Measure Telling Pastors to Affirm LGBT Ideology | CBN News"](https://www1.cbn.com/cbnnews/us/2019/june/the-church-is-under-attack-ca-lawmakers-pass-measure-forcing-pastors-to-embrace-lgbt-ideology):

> A committee in the California State Assembly has passed a resolution telling pastors to affirm homosexuality which, for many pastors, would be a violation of biblical beliefs.
>
> Assemblyman Evan Low and three dozen other lawmakers pushed the resolution in the state Assembly Judiciary Committee that's aimed at telling religious leaders in California what they should preach.

E.g. [Carl and Angel Larsen](https://adflegal.org/detailspages/client-stories-details/carl-and-angel-larsen) own a company that wants to record wedding videos:

> According to Minnesota officials, the State’s Human Rights Act mandates that if the Larsens make films celebrating marriage between one man and one woman, then they must make films celebrating same-sex marriages as well. State officials have repeatedly threatened to prosecute expressive business owners who decline to create speech promoting same-sex marriages. And there are steep penalties for violating
>   the law, including payment of a civil penalty to the state, triple compensatory damages, punitive damages up to $25,000, and even up to 90 days in jail.

Meanwhile, many on the left are demanding that "[trigger warnings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_trigger#Trigger_warnings)" and "[Safe spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_space)" be provided for people that don't want to see or hear what other people are saying and doing.

In one direction, even hearing a word that triggers bad feelings must be prevented, but in the other direction people are forced to not
only hear *about* something, they are forced to participate in it.
Groups that express this kind of biased double-think scare many people, regardless of their political or religious views.

Most Christians don't fear the leftist beliefs themselves, or even oppose anyone's right to hold and express those beliefs.
Their fear comes from knowing that many on the left want the state to legislate and enforce their specific religious-like views.

So it's not so much that Christians support Republicans; it's that Christians find that many people aligned with the Democratic Party are actively destroying what Christians cherish.  And in the USA, when it comes to elections, there *are* only two choices.

Comment: This might have been a good answer if you could have written it without the level of vitriol.

Comment: @divibisan, it didn't help that the original question was phrased as "*Has a major Christian authority taught his subjects that it is righteous to be a Republican?*.  I have now reworded it to make it as objective as I can.  Any apparent bias that is there is not my own political opinion, but my honest view of the almost insanity in the political situation.  And in case it matters, I am not a Christian, nor a Republican, nor even an American, and in my own country, in 14 federal elections, I have never voted for the Conservative party.

Comment: @RayButterworth And yet you are using the "Social Justice Warrior" which is usually used by conservatives as a pejorative term to refer to their political opponents (or rather a strawman carricature of them).

Comment: @Philipp, apparently I'm five years behind the times.  It [used to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_justice_warrior) an appropriate term for those that take on the causes of other groups of people that they see as unable to fight for themselves, but has now become a pejorative.  I'll change "Warrior" to "Activist".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27819)

Comment: Why does @RupertMorrish say "This does not provide an answer to the question."?  The question is "*Why does the Republican party have such a high appeal with Christians?*", and my answer was that "*it's not so much that Christians support Republicans; it's that Christians find that many people aligned with the Democratic Party are actively destroying what Christians cherish [... and] there are only two choices.*".  That  many Christians are rejecting what many Democrats are supporting sounds like an explanation as to why many Christians are siding with the Republicans.

Comment: A good answer would not contain so many unsourced assertions.

Comment: The edit just seems to double down on the unsourced assertions and attacks.